# Action-triggered lock screen

Tags: lock-screens

It's probably not possible, but it's worth an ask.

I've set up my phone in such a way that it won't be obvious to anyone else how to use it.

What I'd like is this:
(a) to NOT have to unlock the phone every single time I use it; but
(b) to have any incorrect use of the phone trigger the lock screen.

I can easily set the launcher to do (b), but it looks like we can't have a lock screen that doesn't come up automatically whenever you use the phone.

...or can we?

Comment: Is Smart Lock not acceptable as a solution? The phone would show lock screen only when it has not been used for at least 4 hours or if the criteria it depends upon can no longer be met. An unsafe option is to remove the lock screen completely and use an app as a lock screen replacement that can also provide the level of flexibility you need. An automation app such as Tasker can create a rudimentary lock screen for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the thought! But no, it's not a solution at all. It's not a way to do what I need, it's a way to do something completely different.
It doesn't protect the phone from people who don't understand the graphic interface I've built. It doesn't trigger the lock screen when *I* want it. It triggers it based on things that don't help me.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to use something like tasker to literally go into settings and TURN ON THE LOCK SCREEN when my trigger is triggered... ?